# Change button_to when updating Cart in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a button_to that adds an object (Image in this case) to a Cart via Ajax, once added i would like to change the button_to to be able to remove that particular image from the Cart. I have implemented something which kind of works (you have to refresh the page though to get the 'remove from cart' button to show, but when removing the button does change).

My current attempt is concerning me, I know it can be a lot cleaner and I think the logic/approach could be incorrect, I'm thinking the database queries could be better, especially as they are in the views. I would like to know how to go about this correctly

View (Images/show)

```
<div id="cart_button">
  <%= render 'shared/cart_button', locals: { image_id: @image } %>
</div>
```

shared/cart_button

```
<% if Cart.where(user_id: current_user, image_id: @image).count == 0 %>
  <%=button_to carts_path(image_id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id), method: :post, :remote => true,do %>
    Add To Cart
  <% end %>
<% elsif Cart.where(user_id: current_user, image_id: @image).count == 1 %>
  <%=button_to cart_path(id: Cart.where(user_id: current_user, image_id: @image).first.id), method: :delete, :remote => true, do %>
    Remove From Cart
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#cart_button").html('<%= j render partial: "shared/cart_button" %>');
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#cart_button").html('<%= j render partial: "shared/cart_button" %>');
```

So the issue I have at the moment is when I add to cart the button does not change, but when I refresh the page the button will then change. Upon removing from cart the button updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if Cart.where(user_id: current_user, image_id: @image).count == 0 %>
```

This is very bad, you shouldn't have logic in views.

All you need to solve the problem is to create two template, one for each button. When you add product to cart, render the template that replaces "Add to cart" button with "Remove from cart". When you click "Remove from cart" button, remove the product from cart and render the template that replaces "Remove from cart" button with "Add to cart" button.

So, the flow looks like this:

1. Render "Add to cart" button.
2. When button is clicked, a request is sent and a product is added to the cart in DB.
3. The response (in `create` action) renders `create.js.erb` template, that replaces the button with "Remove from cart" button.
4. When "Remove from cart" button is clicked, a request is sent to `destroy` action, that removes product from the cart and renders `destroy.js.erb` with JS that replaces button to "Add to cart".

Comment: yes, Logic in views is awful :-( I knew that, just had to figure out a way around that.. Now you have pointed it out it was so simple, thanks

Comment: one question on this though, if i added image 1 to my cart, navigate away from the page and then come back to it, it would render the Add to Cart button, even though it is already in my cart ?

Comment: Yep. You shouldn't just render "Add to cart" button, but add a check for a product being in the cart. I think in index action you should get all products in cart and in the index view, while iterating over products, check if the product is in the cart and render different buttons. The key idea here is to load whole cart for the current user at once and then just check product against it.

Comment: so the check could be a scope in my cart model maybe ? or do you have an example of how you would go about this ?

Comment: No, you just need to load all products in cart, like so: `@cart = Cart.where(user_id: current_user).pluck(:image_id)`. Then when iterating over products in index view, you just check `@cart.includes?(product.id)` and render "Add" button if product is in cart and "Remove" button if it isn't.